# YouTube web no sound but VLC has sound

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, vlc-media-player, youtube

On Windows 7, in YouTube web client (in latest Chrome) - videos play, but without sound. IIRC, they used to play with sound some days earlier on the same machine. Pretty sure I did not change any config opts in between - had no reason to.

Yet, at the same time (now, when YT has no sound), VLC player works fine, has sound.

Had similar problem earlier on another Windows 7 machine of sound getting disabled intermittently. Tried a lot of things in Control Panel / Sound option, but mostly did not work then, nor now.

Comment: Is it 100% limited to youtube and other online web players function (Vimeo, etc.)?

Comment: Did you set Chrome to mute on the volume mixer? Do you use Chrome Toolbox? Some resources from searching on Google: http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/solved-windows-7-keeps-muting-chrome-599836.html, http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/NENAi7jc9fE (about the same as the previous link), http://s3.amazonaws.com/satisfaction-production/s3_images/129672/mixer.png (volume mixer)

Comment: Youtube has its own volume control did you check that?

Comment: cybernard: Turns out you were right. I checked the YouTube volume control, it was set on mute for some reason. Don't think I did it myself. So it looks like the issues given in the links mentioned by others above, also have a part to play in this problem - i.e. only the Chrome volume seems to be getting muted automatically. Weirdly, when I went into the Windows Volume Mixer, I saw the section for Chrome, which was set to muted, and it had a message that it was automatically muted ... not sure how that happens!

Comment: After increasing the volume in both YouTube and the Volume Mixer, I could get sound in the video, and at a good enough volume. Thanks again ...